# Please help me identify two pin locking connector

Tags: power-supply, connector, identification

This is a two pin, locking style connector with "AMP" molded into the front edge; there is also a "P".
Material is nylon or similar and the pins are pushed in from the rear like Molex connectors.
What is "unusual" is the D shaped profile of the "nose" - close but not compatible with other two pin connectors I can easily obtain :(

[image: two pin locking connector]

AMP/Tyco never got back to me and our usual distributors are clueless.
We have a few thousand machines in service with 24 volt power supplies that use this connector (manufacturer of the power supplies is HIPRO - now under new ownership - also not communicating)

Have spent a week trawling through connector catalogs, waited a couple of weeks for Tyco and the power supply folks to get back to me... a bit frustrating.

Comment: Universal Mate-n-Lok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That connector family is called the Mate-n-Lok series. They are great power connectors and have been around for years. They come in two general sizes, the Mini type and the standard or Universal series.

Here is a link to the [Mouser catalogue page](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/catalogusd/647/1833.pdf) for the Mini.

Your two pin is hard to tell from the picture if it is the universal or the mini.

This is [the one you are probably after](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-AMP/350777-4/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuzXLcWrSfMr1OC7C0za10y0ivrk%2FxrMuc%3D):

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1. If EE.SE could have its own badges, we would have a badge `connectorologist`.  It could be awarded for a certain number of upvotes (and/or accepted answers) in questions tagged `connector` and `identification`.

Comment: @NickAlexeev but one can get badges specific to a tag, so just create the connectorologist!  :)

Comment: moreover usually a connectorologist is a life saver